# How to Apply Parallel Processing to Improve Performance of Spatial Analysis in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, geospatial, terra

I've been working on a spatial analysis project in R that involves processing climate data from NetCDF files, performing operations on shapefiles, and aggregating results based on various criteria (e.g., RCP scenarios, resolution, data type). The project processes a significant amount of data and currently runs sequentially, which leads to long execution times. I am interested in optimizing the code through parallel processing to make it more efficient. Below is a simplified version of the script I am using:

```
############
# Clear existing variables
rm(list = ls())

# Load the necessary libraries
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(dplyr)

start_time <- Sys.time()

# Path to the text file containing index names
text_file_path <- "/scratch/.../Index Names_daily.txt"

# Read index names from the text file (skipping the first line if it contains column headers)
index_names <- readLines(text_file_path)[-1]

# User input for file criteria. user options are (COMPLETE)
rcp_scenario <- "rcp85"  # Example RCP scenario 
resolution <- "22i"  # Example resolution
data_type <- "raw"  # Example data type

# Directory containing the NetCDF files and its subdirectories
nc_dir <- "/scratch/.../xclim_output"

# Read the merged shapefile
shapefile_path <- "/scratch/.../merged_with_arctic.shp"
shape <- st_read(shapefile_path)
shape_terra <- vect(shapefile_path)

# Loop through each index name
for (index_name in index_names) {
  # Create the pattern for matching file names, ensuring it starts with the index name
  pattern <- paste0("(^|.*[\\\\/])", index_name, "\\.hist_", rcp_scenario, "_merged.*", resolution, "\\.", data_type, "\\.nc")
  
  # Find all NetCDF files matching the criteria, including in subdirectories
  nc_files <- list.files(path = nc_dir, pattern = pattern, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
  
  # Extract column names (model names) from file paths
  column_names <- sapply(nc_files, function(file_path) {
    sub(".*_merged\\.(.*)\\.nc$", "\\1", basename(file_path))
  })
  
  
  # Initialize variables to track the earliest start date and maximum length of dates
  earliest_start_date <- as.Date("9999-12-31")
  # max_length <- 0
  date_lists <- list()
  # Loop through each NetCDF file to find the earliest start date and maximum length
  for (file_path in nc_files) {
    rast_data <- terra::rast(file_path)
    file_dates <- terra::time(rast_data)
    if (!is.null(file_dates) && length(file_dates) > 0) {
      converted_dates <- as.Date(file_dates, origin = "1970-01-01")
      # Store the converted dates in the list
      date_lists[[file_path]] <- converted_dates
    }
  }
  # Sort the combined dates to ensure chronological order
  dates <- sort(unique(do.call(c, date_lists)))
  
  # Initialize a list to hold data frames for this index name, with an inner structure for polygons
  index_data_structure <- list()
  
  # Loop through each polygon
  for (i in 1:nrow(shape_terra)) {
    single_polygon <- shape_terra[i, ]
    polygon_name <- as.character(terra::values(single_polygon)[["NAME_E"]]) # Adjust attribute name as necessary
    # print(paste(index_name, polygon_name, sep = "_"))
    # Initialize a data frame for this polygon
    polygon_data <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(column_names), nrow = length(dates))), column_names)
    polygon_data$Date <- dates
    
    # Process each NetCDF file for this polygon
    for (nc_index in seq_along(nc_files)) {
      rast_data <- terra::rast(nc_files[nc_index])
      column_name <- column_names[nc_index]
      
      # Initialize column with NAs
      polygon_data[[column_name]] <- NA
      
      # Calculate mean for each time step
      for (j in 1:terra::nlyr(rast_data)) {
        date_of_layer <- as.Date(terra::time(rast_data[[j]]), origin = "1970-01-01") # Make sure daily takes the NAs in the middle of the timesteps
        if (date_of_layer %in% dates) {
          print(paste(index_name, polygon_name, j, sep = "_"))
          row_index <- which(dates == date_of_layer)
          extract_values <- terra::extract(rast_data[[j]], single_polygon, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
          polygon_data[row_index, column_name] <- extract_values[,2] # Assuming the second column contains the mean values
        }
      }
    }
    
    # Assign the data frame to the appropriate polygon name within the index
    index_data_structure[[polygon_name]] <- polygon_data
  }
  
  # Rename the list for this index name dynamically
  assign(paste0(index_name, "_data_structure"), index_data_structure)
}

end_time <- Sys.time()
duration <- end_time - start_time
print(paste("Execution time: ", duration))
```

The script performs several key operations:

- Reads index names from a text file.
- Filters NetCDF files based on user-defined criteria.
- Processes each NetCDF file to extract and compute mean values within polygons from a shapefile.
- Aggregates the results into a data structure for further analysis.

Given the nature of these operations, particularly the nested loops for processing each index name and polygon within shapefiles, I believe parallel processing could significantly reduce execution time. However, I'm not sure how to effectively apply parallel processing techniques to this specific case.